# How to get file extension from this array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
        array(1) {
      ["picture"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(23) "2021-05-14_20-59-00.jpg"
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(24) "K:\xampp\tmp\php4967.tmp"
        ["error"]=>
        int(0)
        ["size"]=>
        int(122314)
      }
    }
```

I only want to get the 2021-05-14_20-59-00.jpg and extract the file extension.

I tried it like this:

`($_FILES['picture']['name'])`

but the output is like this:

`string(23) "2021-05-14_20-59-00.jpg"`

I only want to get this 2021-05-14_20-59-00.jpg so i can put it on the pathinfo argument and extract the extension.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to use [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) on the `$_FILES['picture']['name']`

Comment: Confusing but just `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`.  The only way you would get the ouput you show is running `var_dump` on that var, which is only for debugging.

Comment: `mime_content_type()` can be more reliable, since it infers things that simply the extension may not (FWIW).

Comment: Also, check out https://docs.php.earth/security/uploading/ or some other article about doing secure file uploads. If its a small personal project, you can decide whether to take security seriously or not. But if you're going to have user signin & any personal info anywhere on your server, do be careful.

Comment: Hey Guys, abracadaver is right. I made a mistake. I am putting it on var_dump that's why it's showing the string(33).